# differential (Jacobi Matrix) of $f(A)=A^2$ where $A$ is a matrix - check my answer

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I just want a quick verification that what I did here is correct:

let $f(A)=A^2$ where $A$ is a n by n matrix with real entries.

then $$D_f(A)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(A+tA)-f(A)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(A+tA)^2-A^2}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{A^2+AtA+tAA+t^2A^2-A^2}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2tA^2+t^2A^2}{t} =\lim_{t \to 0} 2A^2+tA^2 =2A^2$$

so overall

$$D_f(A)=2A^2$$

is this correct?

Comment: If the first step follows from the definition, then everything's right.

Comment: Do you want to write $\lim_{T\to 0} \dfrac{f(A+T)-f(A)}{|T|}$? Because the way this is written looks like a directional derivative. I'll add I've never come across these specific kinds of functions, so I imagine it as a vector function in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the definition of the differential. A definition if a map $L$ which maps any $A$ to a linear map $L(A)$ such that 
$$\lim_{\lVert H\lVert\to 0}\frac{f(A+H)-f(A)-L(A)(H)}{\lVert H\rVert}=0.$$
With this definition, we find $Df(A)(H)=AH+HA$.

Here you computed correctly the directional derivative at $A$ in the direction $A$, but we also have to consider the other directions.

Comment: as far as im concerned, the definition of differential is the jacobi matrix. IE the matrix of partial derivatives

Comment: If I understand well, this will involve a coordinate-by-coordinate computation, which can be avoided with the direct method (using the definition of the differential).